# Rails 3.1 Rspec could not find link with text or title "Sign in"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, webrat

I'm trying to have Rspec test for user sign in.  Here is my view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div><%= f.label :email %><br /><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br /><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></div><br />

<div class = "btn"><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Users" do

describe "signin" do

    describe "failure" do
      it "should not sign a user in" do
        visit new_user_session_path
        fill_in "email",    :with => ""
        fill_in "password", :with => ""
        click_link "Sign in"
        response.should have_selector('div.flash.alert',
                                  :content => "Invalid")
        response.should render_template('devise/sessions/new')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the error:

```
1) Users signin failure should not sign a user in
Failure/Error: click_link "Sign in"
Webrat::NotFoundError:
Could not find link with text or title or id "Sign in"
```

I tried 'click_button' but that but I get a noMethodError so that seems to have been removed.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
click_link "Sign in"
```

try

```
click_button "Sign in"
```